# without adding timer or modify the form itself, can we show the form only for specific time span

Tags: c#, winforms

Without modifying the form itself, can we make the from only show for some specific time, say 5 minutes.

Comment: Why are you wanting to avoid using a timer? It seems this would provide the exact functionality you need. Perhaps through discussing your aversion to Timers we can find the answer.

Comment: there are cases we cannot modify the form, ie, the form is from 3rd party.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do:

```
Thread.Sleep(...);
theForm.Invoke(...);
```

But at it's core, that's semantically equivalent to using a timer. The only difference is that the timer will pick a thread from the thread pool and in the "sleep" case you'd have to allocate the thread your self. I would advocate that's better to use the thread pool where you can, which means you should just use a timer.

FYI: You can use a timer without using a `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` control by using the `System.Threading.Timer` class. That would allow you to do what you want without having to modify the form.

Comment: The other difference is that `Thread.Sleep` is a *blocking* call, whereas a timer doesn't block execution of your thread. Other messages can be processed. Often an important distinction, and the subject of many questions here on SO.

Answer (score 1):

There's no reason for the timer to have to be a member of the form.  This will work just fine:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        var frm = new ThirdPartyForm();
        var tmr = new Timer() { Interval = 5*60*1000, Enabled = true };
        tmr.Tick += delegate { frm.Close(); tmr.Dispose(); };
        frm.Show();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you could (*e.g., count to 5 minutes in a separate thread and close the form*) but you would probably only be duplicating the functionality of a timer.

Answer (score 0):

So, the form is 3rd party?  Meaning, not in your program or what?  If you must, you can simply close that form from another form or thread.  If from another form, use a timer object there.

Comment: I have to use application.run to start the 3rd party form.